# Method from base class is called always

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have a base class and a derived class

```
public interface IDispatch {
    void DoSomething();
}

public class Foo : IDispatch {
    void DoSomething() {

    }
}

public class Bar : Foo {
     void DoSomething() {

    }
}
```

I have a function, based on the condition, I'm referencing it.

```
  Foo randomfunc(Foo f){
    if(...){
         f = new Foo();
    }else{
         f = new Bar();
    }
   f.dosomething(); // this works fine
   return f;

    }
```

But in the method call

```
Foo qwe;
qwe = randomfunc(f);
qwe.doSomething(); //it calls doSomething() from Foo() even though it references Bar
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @zerkms After returning , does it lose the reference ?

Comment: who is `f` in `qwe = randomfunc(f);`?

Comment: @DesertFox Foo f; (only declared, reference part is done in the function)

Comment: You do not override `DoSomething` method in `Bar`, but just hide it. So, when you address to `Bar` as to `Foo`, you will always call `Foo`'s method. This shouldn't work fine, it may even be uncompilable due to absense of `public` implementation of interface (compilation error CS0737).

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev hide it, in the sense? How can i fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're *hiding* the methods, not overriding them. In fact, you'll get a warning for the code you've written (assuming you fix the compiler error since you're implementing the interface with private methods).

This:

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {

    }
}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
    public new void DoSomething()
    {

    }
}
```

However, the latter will prevent a warning, as it's telling the compiler "I know what I'm doing".

With method hiding, it means that `Bar`'s implementation will only be invoked *if the object you invoke it on is cast as Bar*. That's the behaviour you're experiencing here. What you *actually* want to do is override the method, not hide it. For example:

```
public class Foo : IDispatch
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {

    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {

    }
}
```